# Float Image to out of DIV

Tags: html, css

I am currently facing a problem in placing an image out of div. I want the image to be floated extreme right of screen irrespective of div screen size.

I built a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jny8380f/)** for the problem that i am facing.

CSS:

```
.outer{
background:cyan;
position:relative;
width:700px;
height:475px;
}
.inner{
width:370px;
color:#fff;
position:absolute;
background:red;
top:35px;
}
```

Image shall look like as below as per solution

[image]

Comment: Why you are using `position:absolute`?

Comment: because i want image to be placed at absolute position. Please suggest a solution,

Comment: You don't have to give it absolute. This is bad structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may help you try this

```
.inner
{
width:100%;
color:#fff;
position:absolute;
background:red;
top:35px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jny8380f/4/)

### another demo without inline style

```
.inner .col-sm-6:nth-child(1)
{
 padding-top:10px;
  width:20%;
  float:left;
}
.anotherdiv
{
 width:80%;
 float:left;
 padding:0;
}
.anotherdiv img{
  widh:100%;
}
```

ijust make these changes in this

[see demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jny8380f/7/)

Comment: i think u forgot the link to fiddle. Anyways the width is fixed for inner box

Comment: because i think you use bootstrap which effect if i make it in style then it may effect another oneso i just do inline

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qyu92hov/)

Snippet:

```
<div class="inner row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="">
        <p>Some helper Text goes here and there</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8" style="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
</div>
```